# Riemann Integrability of$ \frac{1}{x^{1/2}}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a little confused with the link between Riemann integrability and the existence of the integral (that might have been taught in high school). Specifically, in this case if we know that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx = 2 $ (i.e. the integral exists), are we able to then say that it is Riemann integrable?

My confusion stems from the Theorem which states that if $f$ and $g$ are RI on $[a,b]$, then $fg$ (multiplication not composition) is RI on $[a,b]$. But obviously $f(x)f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not RI on $[0,1]$. So this leads me to conclude that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is not RI even though the integral exists. Can someone clarify where I've gone wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: It's not Riemann integrable, as it is not bounded. It is **improperly** Riemann integrable.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is the key word here bounded, and does this extend to Riemann-Stieltjes integrability?

Comment: your function is not defined at zero